# Retain the static/locked Range from Input Box for VLOOKUP

Tags: excel, vlookup, inputbox

I am attempting to use input from `InputBox`, where the `InputBox` determines the TableArray for `VLOOKUP`.

Once the Worksheet and Cells are selected and added to the `VLOOKUP` Formula, they lose the static path and it makes them dynamic.

Example:

```
    Dim PrevBacklog As Range
    Set PrevBacklog = Application.InputBox(prompt:="Select the Worksheet/Tab and cell range for lookup", Title:="Previous Backlog Tab", Type:=8)
    ActiveSheet.Range("I2:I1000").Formula = "=VLOOKUP(A2," & PrevBacklog.Address(0, 0, xlA1, 1) & ",9,False)"
```

InputBox will capture "Sheet2!$A$1:$N$2", but the resulting formula is

```
=VLOOKUP(A2,Sheet2!A1:N2,9,FALSE)
```

This is problematic as it it relative to each cell.  I would like the formula to result in

```
=VLOOKUP(A2,Sheet2!$A$1:$N$2,9,FALSE)
```

How does one retain the locked/static address?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change

```
PrevBacklog.Address(0, 0, xlA1, 1)
```

to

```
PrevBacklog.Address(True, True, xlA1, True)
```

Or more simply, since most of those are the default values:

```
PrevBacklog.Address(External:=True)
```

Comment: @DavidConway - see the edit actually. Also helps to read the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.address) lol.